# Example of a separable space without a Schauder basis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Can I say that the normed linear space $(\Bbb{R}(\Bbb{Q}), \lvert\, \cdot\,\rvert)$ is an infinite dimensional, separable, Banach space and hence cannot have a Schauder basis?

My argument is based on the fact that an infinite dimensional Banach space cannot have a countable basis.

Comment: No. Schauder bases are not Hamel bases. Schauder bases allow representations as infinite linear combinations. Finding a separable Banach space without a Schauder basis is non-trivial. Per Enflo was the first to do so in: Enflo, P.: A counterexample to the approximation property in Banach spaces. Acta Math. 130, 309–317(1973).

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

No. Schauder bases are not Hamel bases. Schauder bases allow representations as infinite linear combinations. Finding a separable Banach space without a Schauder basis is non-trivial. Per Enflo was the first to do so.

In fact, he constructed a separable Banach space without the [Approximation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property). A Banach space that has a Schauder basis also has the Approximation property; so his space also gives an example of a separable Banach space without such a basis. This was done in: Enflo, P., *A counterexample to the approximation property in Banach spaces*, Acta Math. 130, 309–317 (1973).

A link to this paper is [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889774).